# SSRS simultaneous A4 / US Letter formats; strategies, workarounds?

Tags: reporting-services, printing, reporting, reportingservices-2005, ssrs-2008

We have a project that will involve reports being produced in both **A4** and **Letter** formats.

Obviously this can be done dynamically but will screw formatting up big time.

What are your workarounds/strategies to cope with this?

(and no I don't want to create 2 versions of each report if I can help it)

Answer (score 2):

I had to deal with double format once as well. As you said, the only option to really have two nice layouts is to have two versions of the report - no way around that.

The easiest workaround I also used is just to go with the lowest common denominator: The size!

- **A4:** *210mm* × 297mm
- **Letter:** 216mm × *279mm*

So you could design your report to be **210mm x 279mm** and it would fit both sizes (minus margins of course). The problem you have then is that you will have a larger gap in the bottom of the A4 version and a gap to the side of the Letter version.